# Retrigger email routing after adding a default route

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

In Google Admin's Gmail section, under "Dafault routing" we have a rule in the "Also deliver to" section to "Add more recipients".  This delivers emails to a second email account.

I mistakenly made the following sequence of changes to a gmail inbox this morning:

- Remove the existing rule
- Wait some time (in which we received some emails)
- Panic and re-add the rule

There are now some emails which haven't been delivered to the second account.  Is there any way to trigger the action to redeliver these messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to trigger redelivery of email. If they bounced, the sender should retry over the next few hours.